# How to filter results from ansible tower api query

Tags: django, api, ansible, filtering

Using postman, I need to only show results where name=TestWorkflow

Here are results returned for my query: 
Get http://ansible-awx.pxdtools.io:8000/api/v2/workflow_job_template_nodes/

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1323,
            "summary_fields": {
                "workflow_job_template": {
                    "id": 121,
                    "name": "TestWorkflow",
                }
              }
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "summary_fields": {
                "workflow_job_template": {
                    "id": 61,
                    "name": "Livraison en TEST",
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

i already tried many of these filters : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/filtering.html

This query does not work because name is inside results/summary_fields

Get http://ansible-awx.pxdtools.io:8000/api/v2/workflow_job_template_nodes/?name=TestWorkflow

```
{
    "detail": "WorkflowJobTemplateNode has no field named 'name'"
}
```

the expected results i want will be

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1323,
            "summary_fields": {
                "workflow_job_template": {
                    "id": 121,
                    "name": "TestWorkflow",
                }
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the task with [selectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr) below

```
- set_fact:
    results: "{{ data.results|
                 selectattr('summary_fields.workflow_job_template.name',
                            'match',
                            'TestWorkflow')|
                 list }}"
```

Comment: my first idea was to filter directly from my get, but if its not possible your suggest io will work fine i suppose

but i have to fix others things, because my GET have many results so different page to loop, i have to find how to do that.

Comment: There is the option to write your own [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/plugins.html#working-with-plugins). See [examples](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/tree/master/filter_plugins).